# NodeJS Express BasePath with Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
    res.send('pong');
})

app.listen(port);
```

The problem I am having is when I have this in nginx with a base path of /app, it is unable to run the /ping

How can I tell express that it can have /app in front of it without just adding the /app, since it won't have /app locally?

Comment: you have to route the traffic from the nginx proxy to / of your application or you can also try https://gist.github.com/shinuza/2300848

Comment: nevermind, figured it out.. nginx has a rewrite option to rewrite traffic to /

Answer (score 0):

For those that need this..

Nginx has a rewrite option:

```
rewrite /app/(.*) /$1 break;
```

Reference:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html